# Creating tentacular db - How can I cover multiple type of object

Tags: database, grails, hsqldb

I'm working on a Grails application that would handle video games

But more than video game I need my app be able to deal with music cd, dvd or book.
I have my own model to design my VG db but I'm looking (that's my question) for a solution to easily design and integrate model for book, cd, etc.

I'd like to avoid 2 things : 
- Design those myself (it would be poorly designed due to 
- Integrate such "row" and unrafinate db elelments in my app, would make it grow so very much ( ? )

Does it exist some pre-design common model ? 
Some specific template ? 
Is there any method to proceed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some open source database designs for bookstore and videostore on the web. If you search for "bookstore database example" and similar, you will find them.